# Unable to caste a control type to 'System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Lable type

Tags: generics, casting, controls, label

I have this generic function

```
T AddControl<T>() where T : WebControl, new() { 
T ctrl = new T(); 
if (ctrl is Label)  {((Label)ctrl).Text = "FirstName :";}
return ctrl; }
```

I get the error: "Cannot convert Type 'T' to 'System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Lable'" 
What would be the proper way of casting.
Thanks in advance.
BB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as` instead:

```
T AddControl<T>() where T : WebControl, new() { 
    T ctrl = new T();
    Label label = ctrl as Label;
    if (label != null)
    {
        label.Text = "FirstName :";
    }
    return ctrl; 
}
```